# C#: Having static baseclass method returning derived class member

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access the static member of a derived class within a static method of the base class. Is that possible?
The derived class has to be partial. The other partial class is an automatically generated Linq2SQL class.

The method **GetEntityName(ID)** should be static because I want to have access to the method also without instantiating an object of that class. And the method must be able to access **EntityName** why that member has to be static.

### UPDATE

I updated the class to clarify the needed functionality:

```
abstract class A
{
    public static string EntityName = "A";

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string GetEntityName()
    {
        return GetEntityName(ID);
    }

    public static string GetEntityName(int ID)
    {
        return EntityName + " with ID " + ID;
    }
}

// Linq2Sql-Class
partial class B
{
    public B()
    {

    }

}

// Customized Linq2Sql class
partial class B : A
{
    public new static string EntityName = "B";
}        

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // static method uses same logic as in the non-static method
    var result = B.GetEntityName(5); // <-- Should return "B with ID 5" but returns "A with ID 5"

    var BTest = new B
    {
        ID = 6
    };

    var result2 = BTest.GetEntityName(); // <-- Should return "B with ID 6" but returns "A with ID 6"
}
```

Comment: Why all the statics? Why define EntityName again in B when B derived from A and A has EntityName already?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a virtual method. You should declare it in class A as virtual and let it return "A", and then declare it as override and let it return "B".

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for troubles

Comment: You can do it using generics, but it will look like a hack because it is. Don't use static methods for this. Or reintroduce `GetEntityName` in `B` as well (still a hack).

Comment: I have one base class and about 50 entity classes. In the base class I want to have a single method for building a string which depends on the value in the derived class. And I don't want to rewrite the logic in each derived class. 

I also want to have the ability to use a static call of the method in case I don't have an instantiated object of the derived class. That's why the member is static.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to try is actually polymorphism but it requires virtual non-static methods.

In your case, your class B should be like this:

```
partial class B : A
{
    public new static string EntityName = "B";

    public static new string GetEntityName()
    {
        return EntityName;
    }
}
```

Comment: And then possibly get rid of the static member variables EntityName, both in A and in B

Comment: I want to have the ability to use also a static method with the same logic so that I don't have to use an instance of the derived class.

Comment: This will resolve to the wrong value if you have a B cast as an A.

Comment: @Barış I don't want to copy the logic of **GetEntityName** in each derived class...so not a good solution